# How to load a transition without :hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

If you look at the example below, a CSS transition comes to life when hovering over it. How can I achieve this effect without having to hover over it with the mouse? I want to be able to use jQuery to add a class under some circumstances and when it does that, the CSS transition should be triggered. What do I need to change? thanks

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098d1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hvr-bounce-to-right">Bounce To Right</a>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/sdkva2t6/

Comment: Simply move the animation from the `:hover` pseudo-class to the class that is added via jQuery.

Comment: I tried that already but didnt manage to get it to work. Could you please try and provide an example?

Comment: @Angelo https://jsfiddle.net/sdkva2t6/2/  Replacing pseudo class `:hover` with class selector `.hover` in css

Comment: Also FYI what you have is a transition, not an animation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick example! However it only goes one way, the blue color doesnt go back again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: put another timer to change it back and use the jQuery function `removeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout to add class to your element.

for example.

```
 .hvr-bounce-to-right{
//your style
}

.hvr-bounce-to-right.new-class:before{
your hover effect
}
```

then using java script just add this (new-class) using setTimeout. it should work